# PyDev eclipse shows compile error red marks , but runs fine?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

The following code is auto-generated by PyDev eclipse plugin, by choosing "new --> PyDev project" , new "PyDev Module", then choose "Unittest"

but on eclipse editor, it shows a red mark on "import unittest", saying that the module can not be imported. but this thing runs fine. I am using python 2.7 and eclipse 3.6

```
'''
Created on Dec 12, 2012

@author: yang
'''
import unittest


class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def testName(self):
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Are you sure Eclipse is properly configured to use your Python 2.7 interpreter? If you try to run the interpreter inside Eclipse, do you get the same thing as if you did it from a terminal window? In particular, did you do the steps at http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html (if you're on Mac, ignore the part about needing a third-party Python; that was only true up to OS X 10.5)?

Comment: by right-clicking "properties" on project, then show Python interpretor, I see it's only 2.7 (I have only 2.7 on my os anyways)

Comment: plus what interpreter I use does not really matter: since the discrepancy is that the editor shows compile error while running the python code within pydev/eclipse works fine ---- I suppose they use he same interpretor, no matter what version that interpreter is. so if one works, the other should also work

Comment: You didn't tell us that running the script inside Eclipse's interpreter worked. That's why I and someone else both asked you to elaborate: to rule out the possibility that Eclipse is misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is as follows: -

I removed these errors by going to:

`Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> Undefined -> Undefined Variable From Import -> Ignore`

And for import not found errors: -

It may also be,

`Window -> Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> Imports -> Import not found -> Ignore`

We forcibly remove these errors because python interpreter do not have a solution for this.

Let me know if you need further info on this.

Comment: This isn't a solution. The real problem seems to be that the interpreter is not properly configured (thus PyDev is not finding the unittest package).

Answer (score 1):

You must be having a unittest.py file in your local system which is getting confused with unittest module. Rename your file and remove .pyc file along with this.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 reasons for this to fail:

1. The interpreter you have configured doesn't have the .py files, only .pyc files (for PyDev to work properly, you need to have an interpreter with the actual .py files).
2. The interpreter is not properly configured (i.e.: you created some virtualenv which references a parent env but the paths from the parent env were not properly added in the interpreter configuration) -- i.e.: the `/Lib` which has the `unittest` package (with `unittest/__init__.py`) is not added to the **PYTHONPATH** at preferences > pydev > interpreters > python interpreter > select interpreter > libraries).